# Badge ordering/grouping on the help page

Tags: feature-request, badges, help-center

In Help Center > [Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges), most of the badges are grouped by type, e.g. `Citizen Patrol`, `Deputy`, and `Marshal` for raising helpful flags.

However, in the Moderation section, `Suffrage` (Use 30 votes in a day) and `Vox Populi` (Use the maximum 40 votes in a day) are not grouped together.

Is there some subtlety that I am missing (perhaps due to them both being bronze badges) - the common feature being *votes in a day* - or can they be grouped together?

Commenter [dWinder](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6487675/dwinder) pointed out that the same goes for all the bounty-related badgse: `Altruist`, `Benefactor`, `Investor`, and `Promoter`.

Comment: Same goes for all the bounty-related badge: `Altruist`, `Benefactor`, `Investor`, `Promoter`